# how to configure multiple users to access multiple ressources with different rights?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, ldap, access-control

I'm working on a project where I've multiple ressources and multiple users, what I need to do is to associate different access rignts to every user depending on the ressource he wants to access to

The problem is that a simple LDAP server can't implement this kind of situation,

An idea is to use multiple LDAP servers, one for each ressource, then how could I manage them all?

Or is there another authentication process I can use in this case?

Comment: How many ressources do you have? Their quantity is dynamic or static?

Comment: I have as much ressources as the user wants, but once fixed it stays static (I'm using a model driven generation process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring Security](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security) has a special ACL module to handle such situations. The basic idea is that each domain object / ressource may have separate access control list. You need to fill this list with appropriate permissions and add corresponding checks in your code. You can have parent -> child relations between the objects to reduce number of permissions. [Check it out](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/html/domain-acls.html).

Comment: @DavidBrossard Note you can linkify text using `[link text](http://url)`, which is less obtrusive for the reader

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really want to add the link but just fix the typo. Stackoverflow wouldn't let me do a one-character change :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have logic behind the access to the resources, you may want to use a rules authorization language such as XACML.
If the assignment of resources to users is arbitrary then the use of ACLs with Spring Security's ACL module is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that a simple LDAP server can't implement this kind of situation

Mine does. You use LDAP to define the roles associated with each user, then you use web.xml to associate the resources with the roles that are required to access them, then you configure/write your login module such that it looks up the roles of each user when you login. Container-managed security can do all that.

Comment: I don't think roles will solve this problem in a natural way because the access to resources is not based on role membership, but rather is chosen arbitrarily, user by user and object by object.